# .. after filename in path

Tags: windows, unix, path

Is it possible to have a path such as this?

```
c:\folder\file.txt\..
```

It seems to work on Windows, at least from Explorer and with `cd` in the prompt, but I can't find anywhere that actually references using `..` from a *file* instead of a folder. Is is supported on Unix? Will it always work?

This would be useful from code as it would mean not having to use e.g. `os.path.dirname` (Python) or `Path.GetDirectoryName` (C#) when traversing from a file and an absolute path isn't required.

Comment: In Windows it works because the user-mode runtime library uses rule-based resolution of ".." components before passing a path to the kernel. There is no actual ".." component on disk in NTFS, and it's just a regular name in the object manager in the kernel and possibly (not always) a reserved name in the filesystem driver.

Comment: In POSIX systems, using a path like "/folder/file.txt/.." should fail with `ENOTDIR` if "file.txt" is a regular file.